# defining an ideal sheaf of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a scheme. Let $A$ be an ideal of $\Gamma(X, O_X)$. I am wondering what does it mean by $Q$ is the $O_X$ ideal generated by $A$? Also how does one show that ideal sheaf defined in such a way is quasi-coherent? Thank you.

Comment: Take an example, make things concrete. $(z^2+1)$ is an ideal of $O_X(X)=\Bbb{C}[z]$ and it generates an ideal of $O_X(U)=\Bbb{C}[z, (z-a_1)^{-1},\ldots, (z-a_j)^{-1}]$. Then $U\to (z^2+1) O_X(U)$ is a sheaf of $O_X$-modules.

Comment: If you're worried about the "image of a morphism from $O_X^{\oplus I}$", that's actually unnecessary and I had been thinking of the definition of a coherent sheaf when writing that. If you're worried about something else, can you detail your concerns?

Comment: What I would like to understand better are the following. The map $R^{\oplus J}\to R^{\oplus I}\to A$ makes sense, but it's not clear to me how one defines $O_X^{\oplus J}\to O_X^{\oplus I}\to Q$, $Q$ being the sheafification of the presheaf. And the definition of quasi-coherent I have is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01BD. I would like to understand how this follows from what you have described. Thank you

Comment: I have added some explanation. Please comment on the post below if you have a specific question - I did not get a notification for your previous comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is generated by $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ as an ideal of $\Gamma(X,O_X)=R$. Then we can define a map $O_X^{\oplus I}\to O_X$ by multiplying the $i^{th}$ coordinate by $f_i$ and summing. The (sheaf) image of this map is $Q$, the requested sheaf of ideals.

In order to show that this is quasicoherent, consider the corresponding map of rings $R^{\oplus I}\to A$. This has a kernel $K$, and we can choose generators for $K$ as an $R$-module which gives us a map $R^{\oplus J}\to K$. Taking the composite, we get a map $R^{\oplus J}\to R^{\oplus I}\to A$ which demonstrates that $A$ is the cokernel of a map of free modules. Using the same map on $O_X^{\oplus J}\to O_X^{\oplus I}\to Q$, we see that $Q$ is again (globally) a cokernel of free modules and thus quasicoherent.

---

In response to the request for additional clarification:

For any open set $U\subset X$, the restriction homomorphism $res_U:R=O_X(X)\to O_X(U)$ makes $O_X(U)$ in to an $R$-algebra, and thus $O_X^{\oplus I}(U)$ and $O_X^{\oplus J}(U)$ are both $R$-algebras in a natural way. In particular, this means that the maps $O_X^{\oplus J}(U)\to O_X^{\oplus I}(U)$ and $O_X^{\oplus I}\to O_X(U)$ given by $res_U$ applied to the entries of the matrix of the map $R^{\oplus J}\to R^{\oplus I}$ and $R^{\oplus I}\to R$ are also ring homomorphisms, and the fact that the various restriction maps are compatible ring homomorphisms imply that they combine to determine morphisms of sheaves $O_X^{\oplus J}\to O_X^{\oplus I}\to O_X$.

As $Q$ is defined to be the sheaf image of this last map, we get a sequence of maps $O_X^{\oplus J}\to O_X^{\oplus I}\to Q\to 0$, which is exact at $Q$. If we can show that this sequence is exact at $O_X^{\oplus I}$, then we will have verified the definition of $Q$ being quasicoherent (for any point $x\in X$, the open neighborhood is $X$ and the relevant exact sequence is just the same exact sequence we've been talking about above). Showing exactness at $O_X^{\oplus I}$ directly can be a bit of a chore, though - there's a way we can shortcut this rather nicely.

For any scheme $X$, there's a scheme called the affinization of $X$ which is exactly $\operatorname{Spec} O_X(X)$. There's a natural map $X\to \operatorname{Spec} O_X(X)$ coming from the adjunction between global sections and $\operatorname{Spec}$ as functors between rings and schemes (the adjunction means that $\operatorname{Hom}(X,\operatorname{Spec} R) = \operatorname{Hom}(R,\Gamma(X))$ for any scheme $X$ and any ring $R$, so we pick $R=\Gamma(X)$ and take the map on the left side corresponding to $id_R$ on the right side). Let $Y=\operatorname{Spec} R$ be the affinization of $X$. Then as $R^{\oplus J}\to R^{\oplus I} \to A \to 0$ is exact, we get that the corresponding short exact sequence of sheaves on $Y$ given by $O_Y^{\oplus J}\to O_Y^{\oplus I} \to \widetilde{A} \to 0$ is exact, and as pullback is right-exact, the pullback to $X$ of this sequence is precisely $O_X^{\oplus J}\to O_X^{\oplus I}\to Q\to 0$ and this is still exact.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. What is meant by $O_X^{\oplus I}$ and $R^I$?

Comment: The direct sum of those objects, indexed by elements of the set $I$. This is useful because depending on the ideal and the ring, we could need any cardinality of elements to make this construction - writing $^{\oplus I}$ handles this without needing to say extra words about the cardinality issue.

Comment: So $O_X^{\oplus I}(U)$ is the direct sum of $O_X(U)$ indexed by elements of $I$ and $R^I$ is the product of elements of $R$ indexed by elements of $I$?

Comment: No, they're both supposed to be direct sums. I think I just forgot to add the extra $\oplus$ or a sentence indicating they're both supposed to be sums. I've fixed it now.

Comment: I see, thank you. Could you possibly explain what the difference between $R^{\oplus I}$ and $\oplus_{i \in I} R$ is? I still don't quite see this...

Comment: Also do you have to sheafifiy the image to obtain $Q$ or is this not necessary?

Comment: Those two direct sums are the same - usually people choose which one to write based on what looks better in context. The answer for sheafification is that in general you do (images are kernels of cokernels, and whenever one sees "cokernel" one should probably sheafify), but not always - if, for example, $O_X^{\oplus I}\to O_X$ is injective, one does not need to sheafify. (This happens when $A$ is principal, for instance.)

Comment: That's good to know.thank you!